# Were Kenma and Kuroo childhood lovers?

Tags: haikyuu

In the original manga of *Haikyuu*, were Kenma and Kuroo childhood lovers?

Comment: Just for confirmation, did you really mean "childhood *lovers*" instead of "childhood *friends*"? [The Shipping Fandom](https://shipping.fandom.com/wiki/KuroKen) mentioned the latter without mentioning the actual relationship being lovers (i.e. just because they're so close doesn't mean they're lovers... or did I break fans' dream?).

Answer (score 1):

No. They are best friends. No romantic relationship between them was shown in the manga. They are just two kids inthe neighborhood that got close and became friends.